# C# Linq- How to manage paging of a parent child query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Suppose that we have two tables (in SQL Server) as follows :

```
Parent
Child
```

and each parent can have zero or more children
We want to load 10 first parents and their children.(Obviously we can't use TOP 10 because it returns TOP 10 records and not TOP 10 parents)

We can write this SQL Statement

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
     (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Parent ORDER BY Id) AS parents 
 LEFT JOIN 
     Child AS children ON parents.Id = children.ParentID 
 --(and we can add a where clause if we want to filter the result)
```

So far so good but I have two questions to ask :

1. How we can write the same query using Linq (using methods)
2. How can we skip ,say for example 10 parents, and take other 10 parents (with their children of course)?

**UPDATE** : OK to make things even more complicated let suppose that we want to get top 10 parents that their children meet a given criteria,for example their name is like Joe then we have :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10 * 
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
          FROM Parent p 
          INNER JOIN Child c ON p.Id = c.ParentId 
            AND c.Name like '%Joe%') AS p1 ORDER BY Id) AS Parents  
LEFT JOIN 
    Child AS children ON parents.Id = children.ParentID
```

Do I get it right ? this query has to be this complicated ? Is there any easier way to do that ?

Comment: A `SELECT TOP 10 ...` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is pointless - which `TOP 10` do you get if you don't define any **order** ?? You'll get an arbitrary 10 rows.....

Comment: If we do not specify any order we will get our records by the same order that their clustered-index has been written(actually it's a problem of paging :) )

Comment: *If we do not specify any order we will get our records by the same order that their clustered-index has been written* Not necessarily. Parallel plan will throw that out the window. Also, if you have a non-clustered index that covers the columns and its smaller that the clustered index you'll get it in the non-clustered index's order.

Comment: ***NO !!!!*** If you don't specify an  explicit `ORDER BY` - there is ***no  guarantee*** as to which order you'll get your rows back! See [Alex Kuznezow: Without ORDER BY, there's no order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) for more details and a sample that illustrates this point!

Comment: You are right.It seems that it's a breaking change in SQL Server 2012 (It was working as I expected until 2008) thank you for reminding me. Then we should use ORDER BY parent.Id for example

Comment: Again: ***NO!!!*** This is **NOT NEW** in SQL Server 2012 - that's been like this all the time.... in a RDBMS, you ***must*** provide an `ORDER BY` to get an order - period.

Comment: [Another very simple example (just 5 rows!!)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx) that there **is no "natural" order** and no guarantee that anything will be returned in any order - unless you explicitly specify it

Comment: It's strange because we haven't encountered any problem .Thanks a lot for helping me . I will look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can JOIN these two tables with the help of ***Linq Join*** operator in LINQ query syntax.
But before this use  `Take()` extension method for `Parent` table:

```
var res = (from p in context.Parent.Take(10)  // Take 10 elements
              join c in context.Child on p.ID equals c.ParentID into g
                   from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()  // Left join
              select new { Parent = p, Child = c}).ToList();
```

You can use `Skip()` before `Take()` if you want to get next *n* elements. Also, you may need to sort `Parent` before taking some *n* elements. Then it will be like that:

`...context.Parent.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Skip(10).Take(10)...`

***For your update:***

You can try this:

```
var firstPart = (from p in context.Parent  // Take 10 elements
              join c in context.Child on p.ID equals c.ParentID
              where c.Name.Contains("Joe")
              select p).Distinct().Take(10);

var secondPart = from p in firstPart
                 join c in context.Child on p.ID equals c.ParentID into g
                       from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()  // Left join
                  select new { Parent = p, Child = c}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks :)  So there's no simpler way to accomplish this task

Comment: Glad to help. But, what you mean by simpler way?

Comment: You need to do the filtering *before* not *after* if you look at the example given. The `TOP 10` will be evaluated *after* comes after the `WHERE`

Comment: @ta.speot.is I agree with you.

Comment: @Beatles1692 I have updated my answer for your needs. But, anyway for me it will be better to create view in database and then Linq to this view.

Comment: Shouldn't we take distinct result of first part ?(Since we are getting its top 10)